# bash script to rename (mv) a file on a remote machine in linux

Tags: linux, scripting

I would like to have a script rename a remote file (with ssh?). I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use ssh to execute the mv command directly

```
ssh user@remotehost.tld mv file filenew
```

Comment: it's not working

Comment: @elad try harder

Comment: @elad It is working. (perhaps if you tell us *why* it's not working - error messages and the like - you'll get better guidance...)

Comment: @elad: It does work, clearly your configuration is broken. If you tell us what thr error message is that you're getting then there is a chance we can help otherwise your on your own.